# как сохранить nodejs sqlite3.Database(':memory:') бд из памяти в файл?

Tags: javascript, база-данных, node.js, sqlite3, electron

как загрузить и затем сохранить nodejs sqlite3.Database(':memory:') бд в/из памяти в файл после выполнения операций?

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db1 = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');

db1.serialize(function() {
  db1.run("CREATE TABLE lorem (info TEXT)");

  var stmt = db1.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?)");
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      stmt.run("Ipsum " + i);
  }
  stmt.finalize();

  db1.each("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM lorem", function(err, row) {
      console.log(row.id + ": " + row.info);
  });
});
db1.close()

fs.writeFile(...) ...?
```

---

db1.db

Comment: А почему бы просто сразу не использовать файл?

Comment: при использовании файла операции с бд = операции с записью на жд-диск -это медленно, чем когда в памяти.

Comment: Может надо просто включить [WAL](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html)? https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/747#issuecomment-270889293

Comment: Вот ещё можно посмотреть https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3/#better-sqlite3--